# Starting one task after finishing another in python script

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import time
import net

net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,4)
time.sleep(.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,1)
time.sleep(0.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,4)
time.sleep(.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,1)
time.sleep(0.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,4)
time.sleep(.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,1)
time.sleep(0.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,4)
time.sleep(.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,1)
time.sleep(0.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,4)
time.sleep(.010)
net.SendItemDropPacketNew(0,1)
```

This code drops an item to the ground in the game I want, but is selected only on slot 0. If I copy this code and put it in slot 1 instead of 0, it will do the same actions in the same time. I want to wait for slot 0 to finish, and after that I want slot 1 to start.

Comment: Basically: I need to drop first slot 0, after that slot is dropped, start dropping slot 1, then slot 2, then slot 3 etc.

Comment: do you have any way of testing whether slot 0 is full?

Comment: In the slot 0, there are some arrows for example, and the full stack of them are 200, i want to drop 1 by 1 till all of the 200 are dropped, then to start dropping the slot 1, who has already 200 arrows and start dropping again 1 by 1 arrows till there are none left

Comment: i understand what you are trying to do, but you didnt asnwer my question. do you have a way to know WHEN slot 0 is done? if you do, run your code in a loop and every time you are done with the current slot, move to the next slot

Comment: Yes i have a way to know, how to create a loop?

Comment: if you dont know how to make a loop i will have to direct you to a basic tutorial, please learn at least the very basics of python before attempting something as complicated as a game

Comment: I don't want to do a game, i want to do a SCRIPT for the game i play already!

Comment: you're in the wrong place then, stackoverflow is to help people get over obstacles they are stuck on, you aren't stuck you just don't want to. please go do a tutorial and if you are still stuck, tell us when you are stuck on and we will help you

Comment: It is not clear what are the zeros and ones and fours... And what about all the repetition? Do you want to go from 0, to 1, to 2 to 3...? Tell me the sequence you want and how do you know you are DONE then I can give you an answer